# Type hint stored as metadata in clojure?

Tags: clojure, metadata, type-hinting

Here is a simple example:

```
(let [^String y "abc"] (meta y))  ; returns nil
```

There seems to be no metadata at all, why?

According to the doc:

> Type hints are metadata tags placed on symbols or expressions that are
>   consumed by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

`(meta y)` returns the metadata of `y`, not the symbol `y`.
You can't access the symbol `y` in the let body. It is only accessed by the evaluator when evaluating the `let*` special form.

```
(read-string "^String y")
;-> y ;; a symbol

(meta *1)
;-> {:tag String}
```